# Setting Background Color in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Right now, I am using this code to try and set the background color

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(0/255) green:(76/255) blue:(255/255) alpha:1.0]];
```

I am trying to get a lightish blue, but instead, its giving me what would normally be the blueColor blue. How do I get it to show the color I would like?

Answer (score 6):

assumed you are in a SKScene so your "self" has a property backgroundColor and you can change it like that:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the background color of your scene.

```
self.scene.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:76/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

Use SKColor not UIColor. If for both OSX and IOS. If it's just for IOS UIColor is fine.

Comment: True, if he is making this game for ios only. If the game is for osx and ios, then SKColor is needed.

Comment: The code in this answer still has the original problem (caused by integer division).

Comment: ?? It is just a royal blue. not the one i want/ what the rbg should make it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0f/255.0) green:(76.0f/255.0) blue:(255.0f/255.0) alpha:1.0f]];
```

Comment: you should add why this fixes the issue

Comment: I have tried it in my code and found to be different from [UIColor blueColor].